# iAD changes proportions on my universal app

Tags: ios, xcode, iad, ads, ios-universal-app

I'm making a landscape universal app and using iAD for the first time.  When the banner ad is showing, the app is working perfectly, but when it's not showing, the leftmost and rightmost parts of my game are outside of my view.
Is there a way to stop the ad from adjusting the screen size?  Or will the screen size not change when the app is on the store?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details? Basically it seems like your container view for game needs to be have AutoResizingMasks properly set (example):

UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth

i.e.:

**self.yourContainerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;**

So that the view doesn't get stretched away. Hope this might help, not sure about your exact scenario but more details might help though.